# Cardinality of a union of countable sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This proof from the "Proofs from THE BOOK" seems flawed to me.

[image]
[image]

If we take $M = \mathbb N$ then the order of $\widetilde{M}$ will be $\omega^2$ as I see it. So $M$ is not similar to $\widetilde{M}$.
Am I missing something?

This [proof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cardinality_of_Infinite_Union_of_Infinite_Sets) is clear to me, although it's more involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. The proof only works if $\frak m$ is uncountable. Nevertheless, since we can prove the countable case separately, it does not complicate the proofs significantly.

(I don't know "the book" very well, so it might have been proved before for the countable case.)

Comment: I still can't see the logic even if $\frak m$ is uncountable.

Comment: Ah, $M$ is similar to a union of some subset of all $B_\beta$. It's enough for the rest of their proof.